# Using SNMP++ library in application written in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, snmp

I'm new in Swift and I would like if someone could tell me how can I use **SNMP++ lib** (written in **C++**) in a simple iOS application written in **Swift**? how to import the lib and begin coding? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

In 2016, Dariusz Stojaczyk wrote C code to construct probes and deconstruct response of SNMP v1 messages hidden in [a project focused on BER](https://github.com/darsto/cber). That project contains the code necessary to take one or more SNMP OIDs and construct a full SNMP message, then take a response and decode it, but has no networking code to actually do this.

I took this code and [added an ObjectiveC wrapper](https://github.com/dhoerl/cber) that can be used to use the existing code to construct a SNMPv1 message, send it to an endpoint using a Socket, and receive a response with a user settable timeout using a dispatch block.

This code is far simpler than any of the big libraries that offer additional services like walking, v2/v3, and traps. If all you want to do is read one or more OIDs, then you should appreciate this code.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C can be mixed with C++.
That's called Objective-C++ (.mm files)

So if you can get the code into those files, in theory you can create a bridging header to deal with linking your swift files: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2 does not work with C++, [and neither will Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution#out-of-scope). So it's not coming any time soon which means you simply can't develop a Swift app with a C++ library.

However Objective-C works with C++, so although you don't have to write your entire app in Objective-C, any code that deals with a C++ library will have to be written in Objective-C (or in C...).
You can then link your Objective-C code to you Swift app with a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).