# Snmp++ commands in iOS xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, networking, snmp

I'm using SNMP++ library (https://github.com/Zchander/mobile-snmp-plusplus) to implement two commands of Snmp (walk and get).

This library is in C++ wrapped and available to use through ObjC Classes. I successfully integrated this in my Swift. Now when I'm trying to use the method getOid and walkOid, I'm getting no response from the service (Request Time Out). I have no idea how to get it working. my purpose to use this library is to get OS version of the host device from the response of these commands.

Here is the code where I'm calling these methods in Swift class:

```
let port = 161
let snmpVersion: Int = 2
let community = "public"
result = (try! snmp?.getOid("1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1", address: host, snmpVersion: uint(snmpVersion), remotePort: port as NSNumber, withCommunity: community, retry: 2, timeout: 600))!

print("result for getOid = \(result)")
```

Here is the defination of this class in ObjC (using this through bridging header):

```
    - (NSDictionary *)getOid:(NSString *)oid
                 address:(NSString *)hostAddress
             snmpVersion:(uint)version
              remotePort:(NSNumber *)aPort
           withCommunity:(NSString *)community
                   retry:(uint)retries
                 timeout:(uint)timeout
                   error:(NSError * __autoreleasing*)error
    {
    int status;

    uint l_retries;
    uint l_timeout;
    NSNumber *localPort;
    // this is getting called
    snmp_version snmpVersion = version1;
    OctetStr snmpCommunity([community UTF8String]);

    if ( aPort == nil ) {
        localPort = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:161];
    } else localPort = aPort;

    if ( retries > 100 ) {
        l_retries = 100;
    } else l_retries = retries;

    if ( timeout < 100 ) {
        l_timeout = 100;
    } else if ( timeout > 500 ) {
        l_timeout = 500;
    } else l_timeout = timeout;

    switch ( version ) {
        case 1:
            snmpVersion = version1;
            break;
        case 2:
            snmpVersion = version2c;
            break;
        default:
            snmpVersion = version1;
            break;
    }

    // Generate a SNMP++ generic address
    UdpAddress udpAddress([hostAddress UTF8String]);

    // Check if it is a valid address, if we got an invalid address
    // we return a 'nil' dictionary and an error code
    if ( !udpAddress.valid() ) {
        *error = [self constructError:ERR_INVALID_DESTINATION];
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"ERROR SNMPController (getOid:hostAddress:oid:snmpVersion:remotePort:withCommunity:retry:timeout:error:)");
        NSLog(@"ERROR SNMP++ Invalid host address or IP: %@", hostAddress);
        NSLog(@"ERROR ====================");
#endif
        return nil;
    }

    // Check if we got a valid Oid, otherwise use sysDescr
    Oid localOid([oid UTF8String]);
    if ( !localOid.valid() ) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"ERROR SNMPController (getOid:hostAddress:oid:snmpVersion:remotePort:withCommunity:retry:timeout:error:)");
        NSLog(@"ERROR SNMP++ We got an invalid Oid (%@), we are using sysDescr for now (.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0)", oid);
        NSLog(@"ERROR ====================");
#endif
        Oid localOid("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
    }

    // Create the SNMP session
    Snmp snmp(status, 0, (udpAddress.get_ip_version() == Address::version_ipv6));
     NSLog(@"ERROR SELFCHECK Ssnmp session status check  %s",status);
    if ( status != SNMP_CLASS_SUCCESS ) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"ERROR SNMPController (getOid:hostAddress:oid:snmpVersion:remotePort:withCommunity:retry:timeout:error:)");
        NSLog(@"ERROR SNMP++ Could not create session: %s", snmp.error_msg(status));
        NSLog(@"ERROR ====================");
#endif
        *error = [self constructError:ERR_NO_SNMP_SESSION];
        return nil;
    }

    // We are ready to build the SNMP++ object we need
    Pdu pdu;                                    // construct a Pdu object
    Vb vb;                                      // construct a Vb object
    vb.set_oid(localOid);                       // set the Oid portion of the Vb
    pdu += vb;                                  // add the vb to the Pdu

    // Set the port
    udpAddress.set_port([localPort integerValue]);
    CTarget ctarget(udpAddress);                // Make a target using the address

    ctarget.set_version(snmpVersion);           // Set the SNMP version
    ctarget.set_retry(l_retries);               // Set the number of retries
    ctarget.set_timeout(l_timeout);             // Set the timeout for the request
    ctarget.set_readcommunity(snmpCommunity);   // Set the read community name

    // Issue the request, in blocked mode
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"DEBUG SNMPController (getOid:hostAddress:oid:snmpVersion:remotePort:withCommunity:retry:timeout:error:)");
    NSLog(@"DEBUG SNMP++ GET to %@ (oid: %@) with version %d on Port: %d using community %@ with retries %d and timeout %d", hostAddress, oid, version, [aPort integerValue], community, retries, timeout);
    NSLog(@"DEBUG SNMP++ What is the community we are sending.... %s", snmpCommunity.get_printable());
    NSLog(@"DEBUG ====================");
#endif

    SnmpTarget *target;
    target = &ctarget;

    status = snmp.get(pdu, *target);

    NSMutableDictionary *resultsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    if ( status == SNMP_CLASS_SUCCESS ) {
        pdu.get_vb(vb, 0);

#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"DEBUG SNMPController (getOid:hostAddress:oid:snmpVersion:remotePort:withCommunity:retry:timeout:error:)");
        NSLog(@"DEBUG SNMP++ -- Oid: %s", vb.get_printable_oid());
        NSLog(@"DEBUG SNMP++ -- Value: %s", vb.get_printable_value());
#endif

        // Add the result(s) to the resultsDict
        [resultsDict setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:vb.get_printable_value()] forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:vb.get_printable_oid()]];

        if ( (vb.get_syntax() == sNMP_SYNTAX_ENDOFMIBVIEW) ||
             (vb.get_syntax() == sNMP_SYNTAX_NOSUCHINSTANCE) ||
             (vb.get_syntax() == sNMP_SYNTAX_NOSUCHOBJECT)) {

            NSLog(@"ERROR SNMP++ Exception found: %lu", vb.get_syntax());

        } else {

            NSLog(@"ERROR SNMP++ GET Error: %s (%d)", snmp.error_msg(status), status);

        }
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"DEBUG ====================");
#endif
    }

    // Make sure error is nil!

    *error = nil;

    return ( resultsDict != nil ) ? [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:resultsDict] : nil;

}
```

Here is the output:

```
  DEBUG SNMPController (socketStartUp)
DEBUG SNMP++ Socket (sub)system will be initialized
DEBUG ====================
ERROR SELFCHECK Ssnmp session status check  (null)
DEBUG SNMPController (getOid:hostAddress:oid:snmpVersion:remotePort:withCommunity:retry:timeout:error:)
 DEBUG SNMP++ GET to 192.168.1.5 (oid: 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1) with version 2 on Port: 161 using community public with retries 2 and timeout 600
 DEBUG SNMP++ What is the community we are sending.... public
 DEBUG ====================
20180804.14:11:58: 3618: (4)DEBUG  : SNMPMessage: return value for build message: (0)
result for getOid = [:]
queryError =  nil
```

Is there any thing wrong with the parameters I'm passing? but the result remain same even after changing the oid and host ip in parameters. I'm not an objective C developer that's why I'm having hard time figuring out why there is no response and the status is always -5 (i.e for Request Time Out).

Comment: Learn how to capture network packets and then analyze if the code sends out proper data.

Comment: Playing around with this too - I was able to get it to build and run. I had the version set incorrectly to 2, when it needed to be one. I first used the app "MIB Browser" to walk my device, only then did I play with the demo app (I just hardcoded the IP and so only needed to hit GET on each run). Get the WALK working first. Its giving me good info now with correct version. Note that v3 is commented out so you need top be using 1 or 2. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidH I have got it working as well, Snmp on my host devices were disabled that's why i was getting the timeout. After enabling, it all starts working.

Comment: I created a simple way to do what you wanted to do - you can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53907701/1633251